# Extracting a substring

Tags: shell, substring

I have to find a substring where my string starts with **country="** and ends with **"** like following-
 country="NZ"
I have to extract only NZ part and add it to an existing string like-

string+=NZ

Please helP!!!

Comment: which shell?  bash, csh, dos?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` in regular expression mode:

```
string=""
INPUT='country="NZ"'
string+=$(echo $INPUT | sed -r 's/country="(.*?)"/\1/')
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, Can we extract the substring when the string is stored in a file named POS.xml? Actually, there are many strings containing country codes in the format country="NZ" and I want only the codes part.

Answer (score 0):

If your string truly only contains `country="CODE"`, then `cut` works too, using `"` as the delimiter:

```
echo 'country="NZ"' | cut -d\" -f2
```